# Change Dropzone maxFiles Dynamically

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm trying to dynamically update the MaxFiles property each time a new image is uploaded/deleted.
By using the following code its not allowing any image to upload instead of limitize it to maxFiles. And it is not taking the value of the variable `maxFile`, but when i remove `maxFile` variable And put a number then it works fine.
got source code idea from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42730294/10373815).

```
!function ($) {
"use strict";
var Onyx = Onyx || {};


Onyx = {
    init: function() {
        var self = this,
            obj;

        for (obj in self) {
            if ( self.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
                var _method =  self[obj];
                if ( _method.selector !== undefined && _method.init !== undefined ) {
                    if ( $(_method.selector).length > 0 ) {
                        _method.init();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    userFilesDropzone: {
        selector: 'form.dropzone',
        init: function() {
            var base = this,
                container = $(base.selector);

            base.initFileUploader(base, 'form.dropzone');
        },
        initFileUploader: function(base, target) {

            var maxFile = $('.dropzone').attr('data-count');

            var onyxDropzone = new Dropzone(target, {
                url: ($(target).attr("action")) ? $(target).attr("action") : "data.php", // Check that our form has an action attr and if not, set one here
                maxFiles: maxFile, 
                maxFilesize: 5,
                acceptedFiles: ".JPG,.PNG,.JPEG",
            //  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
            //  previewsContainer: "#previews",
                clickable: true,
                uploadMultiple: false,

            });

            onyxDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
                let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                file.upload_ticket = parsedResponse.file_link;
                var imagecount = $('.dropzone').attr('data-count');
                    imagecount = imagecount - 1;
                    $('.dropzone').attr('data-count', imagecount);
            });
        },
    }
  }
}// JavaScript Document

function openImagePopup(id = null) {
   $(".upload-images").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
            var imagecount = response.counts;
            $('.dropzone').attr('data-count', imagecount);
    }
 });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="data.php" class="dropzone files-container" data-count="">
   <div class="fallback">
       <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="imageId" name="imageId">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you a the sample Html code block containing the <div class="dropzone"> with the `data-count` attribute?

Comment: @JonathanLarouche question updated with HTML.

Comment: Please see my answer on this other thread here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72381456/2277301

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Once instanciated, the `Dropzone` plugin will ***remains with the same options*** unless you change the instance inner options ***directly***.

To change options of a Dropzone, you can do this with the following line:

```
$('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.options.maxFiles = newValue;
```

`$('.dropzone')[0]` returns the first dropzone DOM element

`.dropzone.options` return the underlying plugin instance options of the Dropzone. You can now change any options directly on this object.

In you case, you will have to change the function that initiate the popup like follow

```js
function openImagePopup(id = null) {
   $(".upload-images").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response) {
            var imagecount = response.counts;
            $('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.options.maxFiles = imagecount;
    }
 });
}
```

And change the dropzone onSuccess event like this:

```js
onyxDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
    let parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
    file.upload_ticket = parsedResponse.file_link;
    var imagecount = $('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.options.maxFiles - 1;
    $('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.options.maxFiles = imagecount;
});
```

As you can see, You can also remove the data-count="" attribute on you element and reuse the value from the plugin instance `options.maxFiles`

Comment: still have the issue. its working with on click function but not working with `dropzone` while uploading file. its not allowing any file to upload. I think `maxfile` inside dropzone function is still 0.

Comment: Did you tried to `console.log(maxFile)` to see what value is passed to the Dropzone plugin?

Comment: its value is 0 with `console.log(maxFile)`

Comment: Should it be that way? do you set the data-count attribute after instanciating the Dropzone plugin?

Comment: yes on line 33 inside dropzone plugin, before I have used it out side of plugin also, with same result.

Comment: Ok, I might have miss understood your usecase, When you show the upload popup, you want to change the maxFile count to whatever fetch.php tells you, and after any upload you want to reduce the maxFile by 1. Is that what you need? If so, changing the attribute won't have any effect on the Dropzone plugin, you will have to re-init the plugin with new maxFile every time.

Comment: yes exactly, and how to re-init the plugin with new maxFile every time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201392/discussion-between-jonathan-larouche-and-lipon).

Answer (score -1):

After spending a couple of hours of trials and errors I realized using the `maxFiles` setting from Dropzone is not exactly what is expected in many cases. That setting will only limit uploading files through the explorer / drag&drop, but after reload more files can be uploaded. It also does not reflect any failures to the upload on the serrver side (e.g. file size too big).

Changing the value of the `maxFiles` setting of an already initialized Dropzone from outside ot it is impossible. For example reseting the number of allowed files after removing some images with ajax will not work.

To really control the number of files that can be uploaded to the server **the counting must take place on the server**. Then in the Dropzone, in the `success` function, we should handle the ajax response:

```
success: function (file, response) {
    var response_data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    if(!response_data.success) {
        $(file.previewElement).addClass('dz-error');
        $(file.previewElement).addClass('dz- complete');
        $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-error-message').text(response_data.error);
    }
}
```

The `response` is the feedback information provided by the script assigned to the `action` attribute of the Dropzone `<form>`, e.g. `<form action="/uploader">`.